# Using aria-describedby to reference description that contains more than just text

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<label for="input">Description<label>
<textarea id="input" aria-describedby="help"></textarea>
<div id="help">
  <kbd>Enter<kbd> to create a new line
</div>
```

The `aria-describedby` tag references the help text which contains a `<kbd>` element as well. Is this valid? I read the following on MDN:

> Note: The aria-describedby content should only be a text string. If there are important underlying semantics in the content, consider using aria-details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`aria-describedby` entry on MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-describedby):

> The `aria-describedby` property is appropriate when the associated content contains descriptions experienced as plain text. If the content contains a large amount of content, useful semantics, or has a complex structure requiring user navigation, use `aria-details`.

The `<kbd>` element qualifies as "useful semantics". Without it, a screen reader user would just hear—

> Enter to create a new line

—which they might interpret as instructing them to move focus into (e.g. "enter" into) a new area in order to create a new line.

Therefore you should use `aria-details` instead of `aria-describedby`.

Additionally, since all screen readers are different and some might not announce the semantics of the `<kbd>` element, it would be more [robust](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/intro#understanding-the-four-principles-of-accessibility) to reword the text to be—

```
Press <kbd>enter<kbd> to create a new line.
```

—so that it's clearer that "Enter" is a key, even without the semantics provided by `<kbd>`.